# Why is "bundle install" returning an error when building my docker repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-5, bundle, bundler

I'm learning how to build a rails application using docker, and each time I attempt to run `$ docker-compose build web` I get the following error:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 20
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev

# Node.js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - \
&& apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https wget && \
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

# SOURCE CODE

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY . $APP_HOME/
RUN gem install bundler --version 2.0.2 --no-rdoc --no-ri
ADD Gemfile $APP_HOME/
ADD Gemfile.lock $APP_HOME/
RUN bundle install
RUN echo '--color' >> ~/.rspec
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  webpacker:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec bin/webpack-dev-server
    volumes:
      - .:/fancyapp
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/fancyapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - webpacker
```

I'm a complete noob with docker and I honestly can't see what's wrong here.
I'm basing my implementation on [this tutorial](https://www.firehydrant.io/blog/developing-a-ruby-on-rails-app-with-docker-compose/)

Comment: Your bind mount is hiding `./vendor` inside the container with whatever's in your local source tree.  This may or may not be related.  Does it work if you delete the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file (make sure to `COPY` the application code in the `Dockerfile`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command `gem list bundler`, I guess your `bundler` version is less than version 2.

If so, run `gem install bundler -v 2.0.2` to install the latest one.

You can run `gem install --default bundler -v 2.0.2` to make it the default version to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your `Gemfile.lock` says that you use `bundler` with version higher than 2. In this case you you can use 2 ways:

1. decrease your local version
2. add to your docker file string `gem install bundler` (without version). It will install last `bundler`